# how can you sort 2 dimensional String array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, comparator

How can you sort this

```
String  [][] Array11= {{array[i]},{array2[i]},{array3[i]}};
```

brief explanation about what im trying to work:
array contains student ID number
array2 contains student name
array3 contains student course.
All of them are STRING ARRAYS

if i input:

## 1:

ID number: 5
name: A
course: CS

## 2:

ID number: 3
Name: B
course: IT

i should sort it by its ID number so the output would look like this

ID Number   Name   Course
3            B       IT
5            A       CS

or if you have any other suggestions on how to make it work, please help me. :)

Comment: Is there a reason you are storing the data in a 2d array?  Given how the rows seem to be different data it would make better sense to store that data in an actual object then have an array of the object you created.  By storing the data in a 2d array you are obfuscating the actual data that it contains.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace your 2D string array with a 1D array of `Student`s, where you create a `Student` class that has the attributes "id", "name", and "course".

Then you create a class that implements `Comparator<Student>`, say `StudentComparator`.  Its `compare` method should return a negative number, `0`, or a positive number, depending on whether the first `Student` compares to the second `Student` as less than, equal to, or greater than.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom `Comparator`.

Check out [Column Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/column-comparator/) it provides two approaches:

1. create a custom Comparator to sort the Array by a given index
2. use the `ColumnComparator` as a reusuable Comparator simply by specify the index of the column to sort on.

Or a better design is to create a custom  Student Object to store the properties of the Student (Id, Name, Course), then you can use the [Bean Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/), to sort on any of the properties in the class.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are storing the data is not appropriate. I would recommend you to define a class for your Students that implements Comparable. Then overide compareTo() function such that it compares by the course id

```
 public class Student implements Comparable<Student >
 {
  public  int id;
  public  String name;
  public  String course;

  public int compareTo(Student s)
  {
     if(s ==null)
       return 1;

    return id - s.id;
  }

 }
```

Now you can store all your students  in the ArrayList as follows :

```
Student [] studentsList = new Student [sizeOfStudent];
```

Now you can just sort using Arrays utility sort method :

```
Arrays.sort(studentsList);
```

Note: If you want to use a different data structure, then I would recommend using ArrayList instead of an Array.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to stop pretending that you are using C and start actually using Java.

step 1: create an object that contains student id, student name, and student course.

step 2: store these objects in a collection (array, list, other) that makes sense.

step 3; sort the collections.

here is some code:

```
public class StudentBlam implements Comparable<StudentBlam>
{
    private final String course;
    private final String id;
    private final String name;

    public StudentBlam(
        final String course,
        final String id,
        final String name)
    {
        this.course = course;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final StudentBlam other)
    {
        return id.compareTo(other.getId());
    }

    public String getCourse()
    {
        return course;
    }

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```